# Android - How to load User Certificate from system

Tags: java, android, ssl, client-certificates

I am developing an app for Android 5 or superior.

I need to load an SSL client certificate to make requests to an API.

I could achieve to load the certificate from the downloads folder and make the requests:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "certificate.pfx");
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), "password".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());            

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

But I want to know if there is a possibility of loading the certificate from the Android system (of course if I have previously installed in Android like this [post](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/install-ssl-certificate-on-android)).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

add your certificate file into **assets** directory and replace:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "certificate.pfx");
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), "password".toCharArray());
```

with

```
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("certificate.pfx");
clientStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
```